# Check if Typekit has loaded with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, typekit

I'm currently building a layout that animates using jQuery, and I am finding out the width of a div using `.width()`. However, sometimes it is getting the `.width()` before TypeKit has been activated (thus giving an incorrect width).

Is there a way to check when TypeKit has loaded by using an `if statement`?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is.

Instead of calling the usual `try{Typekit.load();}catch(e){}` in your `head` tag, you can use Typekit.load with callbacks ([docs](http://help.typekit.com/customer/portal/articles/6787-font-events)):

```
try {
  Typekit.load({
    loading: function() {
      // JavaScript to execute when fonts start loading
    },
    active: function() {
      // JavaScript to execute when fonts become active
      // this is where you want to init your animation stuff
    },
    inactive: function() {
      // JavaScript to execute when fonts become inactive
    }
  })
} catch(e) {}
```

I've literally just done this for my own project, where I don't have the ability to change that code. So If you're in the same situation, try this:

```
// configure these
var check_interval = 100; // how many ms to leave before checking again
var give_up_after_ms = 2000; // how many ms before we consider the page loaded anyway.

// caches etc
var count = 0;
var count_limit = give_up_after_ms / check_interval;
var html = $("html");
var font_loaded_check_interval;

var check_load_status = function(callback) {

    if(html.hasClass("wf-active") || count >= count_limit) {

        // fonts are loaded or give_up_after_ms was reached

        if(font_loaded_check_interval) {
            clearInterval(font_loaded_check_interval);
            font_loaded_check_interval = null;
        }

        // call the callback
        callback.call(this);
        return true;

    }

    count++;
    return false;

};

function doneCallback() {
    // code to run when fonts are loaded or timeout reached
    alert("Done");
}

// check on initial run of JS, and if not ready, start checking at regular intervals. 
if( ! check_load_status(doneCallback)) {
    font_loaded_check_interval = setInterval(function() {
        check_load_status(doneCallback);
    }, check_interval);
}
```